# NativeBaseProvider seems to prevent component export

Tags: react-native, native-base

I ran into the error `useTheme` must be used within `NativeBaseConfigProvider` so read the docs and figured everything should be wrapped in `NativeBaseProvider` and so I did but ever since I get a render error. When I comment all the new imports everything works fine so I don't understand why it says to check the render method of the component

Here's the code

```
import {
    StyleSheet,
    View,
    // Text,
    FlatList,
  } from "react-native";
  import React, { useEffect, useState } from "react";
  import {
    Container,
    Header,
    Icon,
    Item,
    Input,
    Text,
    NativeBaseProvider,
    Box,
  } from "native-base";
  
  // const data = require("");
  import data from "../../assets/data/products.json";
  import ProductList from "./ProductList";
  
  const ProductContainer = () => {
    const [products, setProducts] = useState([]);
    const [productsFiltered, setProductsFiltered] = useState([]);
  
    useEffect(() => {
      setProducts(data);
      setProductsFiltered(data);
      return () => {
        setProducts([]);
      };
    }, []);
  
    return (
      <NativeBaseProvider>
        <Container>
          <Header searchBar rounded>
            <Item>
              <Icon name="ios-search" />
              <Input placeholder="Search" />
            </Item>
            <Icon name="ios-people" />
          </Header>
  
          <View style={styles.container}>
         
            <View style={styles.listContainer}>
              <FlatList
                horizontal
                data={products}
                renderItem={({ item }) => (
                  <ProductList key={item.id} item={item} />
                )}
                keyExtractor={(item) => item.name}
              />
            </View>
          </View>
        </Container>
      </NativeBaseProvider>
    );
  };
  
  export default ProductContainer;
  
  const styles = StyleSheet.create({
    container: {
  
    },
    listContainer: {

    },
    center: {

    },
  });
```

Comment: any update on this? facing the same issue.

Comment: No I gave up on it. But what I can tell you is that `NativeBaseProvider` is actually to be wrapping the app.js and you can avoid the bug by commenting the Header in ProductContainer. Here's is a doc for you https://docs.nativebase.io/setup-provider